# Bootstrap Column 6 Image Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

Now, this is a new project, so I need some help.

I have the following code. Please press full screen.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title>Stack Overflow Question</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/home.css">
  <!-- Reference to main CSS Style File-->
  <style>

  
  ul {
   margin:0 auto;
   border-top:2px solid #000;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
   padding:10px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family:"montserratlight";
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">

   <div id = "navigation">
    <p>
     <ul class="col-md-12"> 
      <!-- MAIN NENU BAR -->
      <li><a href="home.html" class="active"><b>Home</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">Why Does This</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Not</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactUs.html">Work</a></li>
     </ul>
     <!-- Unordered lists.-->
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class = "row">
   <!-- Declaration of First Row -->
    <div class="imageHolder col-md-12 hvr-underline-from-center"> 
    <!-- Image Container as DIV -->
     <div class = "imageInside" >
      <img id = "imageHomeJPG" src="http://s30.postimg.org/8wav359r5/NYC.jpg" style="width:100%" />
     </div>
     <!-- Image Link -->
       </div> 
   </div>
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="about.html">
      <img src = "http://s30.postimg.org/mehrfflwh/Place1.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px; width:100%;"/>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="about.html">
      <img src = "http://s30.postimg.org/iw5rj1l0h/Place2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px; width:100%;"/>
      </a>
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now, when expanded, this is what the website shows.

[image: Screenshot of full website.]

However, there is a small gap between both column 6 photos.

[image: The Gap between the photos]

```
<div class="row" style="padding-right:0">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        IMAGE TAG 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0">
        IMAGE TAG
</div>
```

This produced the following - 
[image: When Padding was removed]

You can see that the image on the left is bigger on the right and therefore it is not correct. 
My question is, how can I make the gap between the two columns smaller (to around 10px) without needing to change the padding? I want to make the images bigger in order to decrease the size of the gap, but I can't seem to find a way!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class :

```
no-space { 
       Width: 100% !important;
       Margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Then put this class in next to where col-md-6 is seep rated by a space like this :

```
Class="col-md-6 no-space"
```

And there should be no spaces between the photos now.

Comment: what if I want the space to be 10px wide?

Comment: Then put the margin to 5px or the width to 95%

Answer (score 0):

To actually solve this question too, what I can also do is go to the Bootstrap CSS file and edit the `padding-left` and `padding-right` values to equal amounts. 
Originally, both values are set at

```
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
```

but looking at other examples such as airBnb, their padding is both set at `12.5` so this is also another solution.